# How can I see all modules that a specific Perl module requires?

Tags: perl, module, include, trace, audit

Let's say I'm given a module like `Data::Validate::IP` and I want to see all modules this requires (`use`s), how can I go about it? I'm looking to audit a module for its dependencies.

Comment: @Braiam the reason why it needs [tag:module] is because the goal here is to **trace** the imports that a specific module does. Not because I'm looking _for_ a module.

Comment: That tag doesn't add anything that isn't included in the title. You don't need to write titles with tags. If someone knows about Python modules they will not be able to answer the question, same with the other tags. Perl on the other hand is pretty critical for the question.

Comment: @Braiam the purpose of tags is to increase searchability. It's so I can search `[perl] + [audit]` and the like or `[module] + [perl] dependencies` and find the question.

Comment: "the purpose of tags is to increase searchability" [citation needed] In fact, I will tell you the purpose of tags: [Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) None of that is about searchbility. Search engines use keywords not tags.

Comment: @Braiam citation in your very link ***When naming a tag, think about how someone would search for that subject.** In most cases this means typing out the full name, but you may also want to use the abbreviation. For example, [css] is probably more appropriate than [cascading-style-sheets]* I even provided the example.

Comment: Even as a *"means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer"* you're referring to searching, whether manually or by filters (automatically).

Comment: Also see the top of the page you linked ["Tags can also be used to help you identify questions that are interesting or relevant to you."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics)  which takes you to the "Browse by tag" and "Search tags" section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Import Tracing

You can use [`Devel::TraceUse`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::TraceUse) to see all modules that a module in question uses,

```
perl -d:TraceUse -MData::Validate::IP -e1
```

Note that it only tests compile time includes like that, to see all of the code that it may pull in with `require` and the like, try actually running the code,

```
perl -d:TraceUse -MData::Validate::IP -e'Data::Validate::IP::is_ipv4("1.2.3.4")'
```

Example output

```
Modules used from -e:
   1.  Data::Validate::IP 0.27, -e line 0 [main]
   2.    strict 1.11, Data/Validate/IP.pm line 3
   3.    warnings 1.47, Data/Validate/IP.pm line 4
   4.    NetAddr::IP  4.079, Data/Validate/IP.pm line 10
   5.      Carp 1.50, NetAddr/IP.pm line 7
   6.        overloading 0.02, Carp.pm line 170
   7.        Exporter 5.74, Carp.pm line 224
  18.          Exporter::Heavy 5.74, Exporter.pm line 16
   8.      NetAddr::IP::Lite 1.57, NetAddr/IP.pm line 8
   9.        NetAddr::IP::InetBase 0.08, NetAddr/IP/Lite.pm line 17
  10.          vars 1.05, NetAddr/IP/InetBase.pm line 8
  11.            warnings::register 1.04, vars.pm line 7
  12.          AutoLoader 5.74, NetAddr/IP/InetBase.pm line 9
  15.            auto/NetAddr/IP/InetBase/AF_INET6.al, AutoLoader.pm line 34 (FAILED)
  13.          Socket 2.029, NetAddr/IP/InetBase.pm line 77
  14.            XSLoader 0.30, Socket.pm line 701
  16.          Socket6 0.29, NetAddr/IP/InetBase.pm line 85
  17.            base 2.27, Socket6.pm line 215
  19.        NetAddr::IP::Util 1.53, NetAddr/IP/Lite.pm line 31
  20.          NetAddr::IP::Util_IS 1, NetAddr/IP/Util.pm line 10
  21.        overload 1.31, NetAddr/IP/Lite.pm line 280
  22.    Scalar::Util 1.55, Data/Validate/IP.pm line 11
  23.      List::Util 1.55, Scalar/Util.pm line 23
Modules used, but not reported:
  /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/532/lib/perl5/cpanel_lib/x86_64-linux-64int/auto/NetAddr/IP/InetBase/autosplit.ix
  /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/532/lib/perl5/cpanel_lib/x86_64-linux-64int/auto/NetAddr/IP/InetBase/inet_any2n.al
  /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/532/lib/perl5/cpanel_lib/x86_64-linux-64int/auto/NetAddr/IP/InetBase/ipv6_aton.al
  /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/532/lib/perl5/cpanel_lib/x86_64-linux-64int/auto/NetAddr/IP/Util/autosplit.ix
  /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/532/lib/perl5/cpanel_lib/x86_64-linux-64int/auto/NetAddr/IP/autosplit.ix
```

Comment: There's also `perl -MData::Validate::IP -E'say for sort keys %INC'` though that doesn't give you a neat tree.

Answer (score 4):

These services can show you declared dependencies:

- [MetaCPAN](https://www.metacpan.org) shows a dependency list for modules. It also shows "reverse dependencies" so you can see what uses a module.
- [CPAN Dependency Graphs](https://cpandeps.grinnz.com) will show you the dependency info as an image.
- I often look at the results of `%INC`, which shows what was loaded (but not by whom). This is handy while trying to get 100% test coverage to know that you got most things. However, this still doesn't pick up optional or dynamic modules unless the code uses them.

The `cpandeps` tool from [CPAN::Dependencies](https://www.metacpan.org/pod/CPAN::Dependencies) is handy too:

```
$ cpandeps Business::ISBN
Business::ISBN (dist: B/BD/BDFOY/Business-ISBN-3.006.tar.gz)
  Business::ISBN::Data (dist: B/BD/BDFOY/Business-ISBN-Data-20210112.006.tar.gz)
    Carp (dist: X/XS/XSAWYERX/Carp-1.50.tar.gz)
      Exporter (dist: T/TO/TODDR/Exporter-5.74.tar.gz)
      IPC::Open3 (dist: S/SH/SHAY/perl-5.32.1.tar.gz)
      Test::More (dist: E/EX/EXODIST/Test-Simple-1.302183.tar.gz)
        File::Temp (dist: E/ET/ETHER/File-Temp-0.2311.tar.gz)
          File::Path (dist: J/JK/JKEENAN/File-Path-2.18.tar.gz)
            File::Spec::Functions (dist: X/XS/XSAWYERX/PathTools-3.75.tar.gz)
              Scalar::Util (dist: P/PE/PEVANS/Scalar-List-Utils-1.55.tar.gz)
          parent (dist: C/CO/CORION/parent-0.238.tar.gz)
        Storable (dist: X/XS/XSAWYERX/Storable-3.15.tar.gz)
          XSLoader (dist: S/SA/SAPER/XSLoader-0.24.tar.gz)
    ExtUtils::MakeMaker (dist: B/BI/BINGOS/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.60.tar.gz)
      Encode (dist: D/DA/DANKOGAI/Encode-3.08.tar.gz)
      Pod::Man (dist: R/RR/RRA/podlators-4.14.tar.gz)
        Pod::Simple (dist: K/KH/KHW/Pod-Simple-3.42.tar.gz)
          Pod::Escapes (dist: N/NE/NEILB/Pod-Escapes-1.07.tar.gz)
          Test (dist: J/JE/JESSE/Test-1.26.tar.gz)
          Text::Wrap (dist: M/MU/MUIR/modules/Text-Tabs+Wrap-2013.0523.tar.gz)
          if (dist: X/XS/XSAWYERX/if-0.0608.tar.gz)
```

There are various static analysis tools too:

- I wrote [Module::Extract::Use](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Extract::Use) to pull out namespaces that show up in particular situations (`use`, `require`, `base`, `parent`). The literal bareword needs to be there though.
- [MetaCPAN::Client](https://metacpan.org/pod/MetaCPAN::Client) and [Module::CoreList](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::CoreList) can configure the information in various ways. Here, I get all the runtime dependencies that aren't perl itself, nor a core module. You could filter on other things though:

```perl
use v5.10;

use MetaCPAN::Client;
use Module::CoreList;

my $metacpan = MetaCPAN::Client->new;

my @queue = map { [ 0, $_ ] } @ARGV;

while( my $tuple = shift @queue ) {
    state %Seen;

    my $release = eval { $metacpan->release( $tuple->[1] =~ s/::/-/gr ) };
    next unless $release;
    say "\t" x $tuple->[0], $release->distribution, 
        defined $tuple->[2] ? " $tuple->[2]" : '';
    push @queue,
        map  { [ $tuple->[0] + 1, $_->{module}, $_->{version} ] }
        grep { $_->{module} ne 'perl' }
        grep { $_->{phase}  eq 'runtime' }
        grep { ! Module::CoreList::is_core( $_->{module}, undef, $^V ) }
        grep { ! $Seen{ $_->{module} }++ }
        $release->dependency->@*;
    }
```